# How to append all the row data into same file name associated with the same file from different rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to generate files based on Column A and it writes Row data into generated files.
Which I am able to achieve with the below code.

Problem:
If a file name appears many times, I want to append all the row data into same file name associated with the same file name from different rows.

As of now it picks the last row associate the the file name in Column A and generates a file.

How to append all the row data into one file.

My code,

```
Sub ExportToNotepad()
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFile As Object

Dim i&, lastRow&
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\WriteToFile\" & Cells(i, 1) & ".xml")

oFile.WriteLine Cells(i, 2).Value
oFile.Close

Next i
Set fso = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing

End Sub
```

Problem Image,

[image]

Comment: sort the data before exporting the files

Answer (score 0):

Your program only gives the last row of data for each file because you are creating each row instead of appending.  Some fso links:
[FileSystemObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object) [FileObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/file-object) [TextStreamObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/textstream-object)
This gives an example of appending

```
Sub ExportToNotepad()
  ' This only appends to existing files
  Const ForAppending = 8 ' if needed
  Dim fso As Object ' FileSystemObject
  Dim tso As Object ' TextStreamObject
  Dim fileo As Object ' FileObject
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim i&, lastRow&
  lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  For i = 2 To lastRow
    Set fileo = fso.GetFile("C:\WriteToFile\" & Cells(i, 1) & ".xml")
    Set tso = fileo.OpenAsTextStream(ForAppending)
    tso.WriteLine Cells(i, 2).Value
    tso.Close
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, let me the try the above code example.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe :

```
Sub test()
Set rngSource = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

rngSource.Copy Range("AA1")
Range("AA:AA").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
Set rngUnique = Range("AA1", Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

Set lr = Cells(rngSource.Rows.Count, rngSource.Column)
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each cell In rngUnique
n = Application.CountIf(rngSource, cell.Value)
Set c = rngSource.Find(cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole, after:=lr)

Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\WriteToFile\" & cell.Value & ".xml")
For i = 1 To n
oFile.WriteLine c.Offset(0, 1).Value
Set c = rngSource.FindNext(c)
Next i
Next

rngUnique.ClearContents
End Sub
```

This code is using column helper (column AA) for unique values, in case
another same value appear in not a consecutive rows. Please make sure that
there won't be important text/value in column AA.

Comment: Thank you so very much,you have given the complete solution to my problem.
Many thanks sir.

Comment: Thanks for your great inputs, instead of writing into a new line, how I can write each line into columns as a CSV file.